# Get current cell column index in DataGridView CurrentCellChanged Event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, event-handling

I have the `CurrentCellChanged` event handler of a `DataGridView` and i want to be able to access the current selected cells column index from the event handler.

I used to have the code in the `CellClick` handler which has `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` as a parameter so i was able to get the column index from the event args parameter but the `CurrentCellChanged` event has `EventArgs` as parameters which i believe is supposed to imply that theres no data for this event.

Is there a way to access the new currently selected cells column index?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `DataGridView.CurrentCell` property ..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx

```
int columnIndex = dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
int rowIndex = dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Use the DataGridView's CurrentCell property.

```
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting, that if someone is using **WPF** (with the **DataGrid**, rather than DataGridView), they can simply do:

```
DataGrid currentGrid = sender as DataGrid;
```

and then

```
currentGrid.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex
```

or

```
currentGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna check it with header of the column then

```
dataGridView.CurrentCell.Column.Header
```

Comment: CurrentCell.OwningColumn.HeaderText