# C# WPF DataGrid change Column Index by Position of Header

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a C# WPF Application where i use a DataTable as Source for a DataGrid.

Now when The User moves a Column in the DataGrid(I already found a ColumnReordered Event)
I want to change the index of the Column to the Position, 
that the User moved it to(0 for the first position, 1 for the second...)

I want to do that because i want to save the column positions for the next time the User runs the Apllication.

Is there any possible way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is whenever user is about to close the form you get the column name and its respective index and save that to any format like xml, csv. Next time when user loads you can apply the re-oredering after reading his last specified settings from the file.

You can have a look at this article for what i mean. This implements the same idea. You can modify it for your WPF application though.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37087/DataGridView-that-Saves-Column-Order-Width-and-Vis

Comment: This sounds kind of helpful, but unfortunately WPF doesent know many dataGrid Attributes such as DisplayIndex

Comment: @LPL i have mentioned in my answer that it is for winforms. and you need to modify it for wpf

Comment: Surprisingly DisplayIndex works right now. 
I am sure when i wanted to use it earlier it wouldn't work for Wpf :D

Comment: @ninzide You can get the display index like this dataGrid.Columns[i].DisplayIndex

Answer (score 0):

Use the ColumnIndex

```
 int columnIndex = dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
```

Post that is already on here should help;

[Get current cell column index in DataGridView CurrentCellChanged Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749747/get-current-cell-column-index-in-datagridview-currentcellchanged-event)

Comment: is .SelectedIndex(); giving me the Index that it had before even if it is on another position?

And if so how can i find out on which Position it is now?

Comment: SelectedIndex(); will give you the current index that is selected. So if you wanted the previous item index then your would need to store that before moving to the next. Im sure you can use the fire events, there is even on for Index changed. But as LPLpointed out, you are after the column index not the row index. I have update my answer for columns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071346/get-column-index-by-column-header-in-wpf-datagrid